# In Scala 2.8, how to access a substring by its length and starting index?

Tags: datetime, scala, string

I've got date and time in separate fields, in yyyyMMdd and HHmmss formats respectively. To parse them I think to construct a yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss string and feed this to joda-time constructor. So I am looking to get 1-st 4 digits, then 2 digits starting from the index 5, etc. How to achieve this? List.fromString(String) (which I found [here](http://scala.sygneca.com/common/string-manipulation)) seems to be broken.

Comment: string.substring(x) or string.substring(x,y)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use the `substring()` method on the string. Note that Scala strings behave like Java strings (with some extra methods), so anything that's in `java.lang.String` can also be used on Scala strings.

```
val s = "20100903"
val t = s.substring(0, 4) // t will contain "2010"
```

(Note that the arguments are not length and starting index, but starting index (inclusive) and ending index (exclusive)).

But if this is about parsing dates, why don't you just use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, like you would in Java?

```
val s = "20100903"
val fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd")
val date = fmt.parse(s)  // will give you a java.util.Date object
```

Answer (score 15):

The `substring` method certainly can get you there but String in Scala 2.8 also supports all other methods on sequences. The [ScalaDoc for class StringOps](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html) gives a complete list.

In particular, the `splitAt` method comes in handly. Here's a REPL interaction which shows how.

```
scala> val ymd = "yyyyMMdd"
ymd: java.lang.String = yyyyMMdd

scala> val (y, md) = ymd splitAt 4
y: String = yyyy
md: String = MMdd

scala> val (m, d) = md splitAt 2
m: String = MM
d: String = dd

scala> y+"-"+m+"-"+d
res3: java.lang.String = yyyy-MM-dd
```

Comment: Well, it's Martin himself. There's a great chance his answer is right :p

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Joda Time, you should be able to use

```
val date = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd, HHmmss")
                         .parseDateTime(field1 + ", " + field2)
```

For the more general problem of parsing Strings like this, it can be helpful to use a Regex (although I wouldn't recommend it in this case):

```
scala> val Date = "(\\d\\d\\d\\d)(\\d\\d)(\\d\\d)".r
Date: scala.util.matching.Regex = (\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)

scala> "20100903" match { 
     |    case Date(year, month, day) => year + "-" + month + "-" + day 
     | }
res1: java.lang.String = 2010-09-03
```

Answer (score 2):

```
val field1="20100903"
val field2="100925"
val year = field1.substring(1,5)
val month = field1.substring(5,7)
val day = ...
...
val toYodaTime = year + "-" + month+"-"+day+ ...
```